# Remove whitespace from vim yank register?

Tags: vim

Whenever I yank something into a vim register with, say, `"tyit` (yank everything between tags into register `t`), I get a lot of whitespace. Instead of `foo bar` I get `foo^M [lots of whitespace here] bar`. Is there some way I can ignore or replace all this whitespace?

Comment: the whitespaces would be indentations and line breaks. you want to remove all indentations and line breaks?

Comment: Yep, it's just xml so it doesn't matter

Answer (score 2):

I actually just figured this out myself:

```
:let @t = substitute(@t, '\_s\{2,}', ' ', 'g')
```

Explanation: substitute all whitespace of two or more characters with one space, globally, and remap it to the same register `t`.

Comment: didn't see you have already found solution. but there would be a typo I guess you meant `\_s` .

Comment: also, this won't remove single line break, because you said `\{2,}` you could consider to use `\_s\+` see my deleted answer